# set a custom multiselect via JIRA REST API

Tags: php, rest, jira

I'm trying to set a custom field of type Multiselect via JIRA rest API using php.  For reason I'm getting the following error:

> {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"Functionality Impacted":"expected 'value' property to be a string"}}

I have the following code for setting the custom field:

```
 public function requestRemedy($summary, $description,  $priority,  $goliveDate,$startTime,
                                 $endTime,$clientImpact,$impactedFunctionality,$fundTransfers ,$fieldAffected, $remedyChangeType,
                                 $changeReason,$remedyImpact, $urgency,$riskLevel,$nameRequestor,$emailRequestor)

{




    $json = Array ( "fields" => Array (
        "project" => Array
        ( "id" => 10051 ),
        "summary" => $summary,
        "description" =>$description,
        "issuetype" => Array ( "name" => "Remedy Change Management" ),

        "priority" => Array("id" => $priority),

        "customfield_13774" => $goliveDate,
        "customfield_14408" => "$startTime",
        "customfield_14409" =>  "$endTime",
        "customfield_14412" => "$clientImpact",

        "customfield_14908" =>Array ( 0 => Array(
            "value" => ($impactedFunctionality),


        )),

        "customfield_14414" => Array("id" =>$fundTransfers),
        // "customfield_14415" =>Array("id" => $businessOnline,"child" =>Array("id" => $businessDependency) ),
        "customfield_14602" => Array("id" =>$fieldAffected),
        "customfield_14422" => Array("id" =>$remedyChangeType),
        "customfield_14423" => Array("id" =>$changeReason),
        "customfield_14424" => Array("id" =>$remedyImpact),
        "customfield_14425" => Array("id" =>$urgency),
        "customfield_14426" => Array("id" =>$riskLevel),
        "customfield_14700"=>$nameRequestor,
        "customfield_14702"=>$emailRequestor

    )
    );

    return $json;
}
```

After adding some dummy data to test the final structure of json, I get the following result:

```
{
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "id": 10051
    },
    "summary": "Test",
    "description": "Human DeSC",
    "issuetype": {
        "name": "Remedy Change Management"
    },
    "priority": {
        "id": "2"
    },
    "customfield_13774": "2016-11-08",
    "customfield_14408": "2016-11-01T07:35:00.000+0200",
    "customfield_14409": "2016-11-01T08:35:00.000+0200",
    "customfield_14412": "cLIENT iMPACT",
    "customfield_14908": [{
        "value": ["Savings Accounts", "Current Accounts", "Call Deposits"]
    }],
    "customfield_14414": {
        "id": "13647"
    },
    "customfield_14602": {
        "id": "14022"
    },
    "customfield_14422": {
        "id": "13712"
    },
    "customfield_14423": {
        "id": "13718"
    },
    "customfield_14424": {
        "id": "13722"
    },
    "customfield_14425": {
        "id": "13726"
    },
    "customfield_14426": {
        "id": "13730"
    },
    "customfield_14700": "Pastor Dan",
    "customfield_14702": "email@time.com"
}
}
```

Which means the issue is here:

```
"customfield_14908": [{
        "value": ["Savings Accounts", "Current Accounts", "Call Deposits"]
    }],
```

the expected structure is:

```
"customfield_10008": [ {"value": "Savings Accounts" }, {"value": "Current Accounts" }, {"value": "Call Deposits" }]
```

Now I'm not sure how to build this using an associative array

The custom field I'm trying to set is customfield_14908.  What I'm finding weird is that I used similar code for setting a multiselect field on JIRA version 7.2.1 and it works well, but not working on JIRA version 7.0.

Comment: What does $json look like once it's built? Better yet, use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test this exact API call with the same data generated in $json.  Some APIs expect numbers and dates to be passed as strings in json.

Comment: Also, why is ($impactedFunctionality) in brackets on its own?

Comment: @HeyZiko thanks for the input, I edited the question. I also added the json out